# Convert text to html bootstrap bash script

Tags: html, bash, twitter-bootstrap, text

I just want to know how to convert this text into html for bootstrap using bash for doing this.

Thanks in advance !

Sample Text:

```
2016-06-05 00:00 2016-06-06 00:00 Outlander Saison 2 Episode 9 Netflix
2016-06-05 17:55 2016-06-05 18:45 Hawaii 5-0 Saison 6 Episode 22 RTS Un (Suisse)
2016-06-05 20:40 2016-06-05 22:20 Madam Secretary Saison 2 Episode 13 & 14 Téva (France)
2016-06-05 20:40 2016-06-05 22:10 The Walking Dead Saison 6 Episode 7 & 8 OCS Choc (France)
2016-06-05 21:15 2016-06-05 22:45 Major Crimes Saison 4 Episode 3 & 4 RTS Un (Suisse)
2016-06-05 22:10 2016-06-05 23:10 Ash vs Evil Dead Saison 1 Episode 7 & 8 OCS Choc
2016-06-05 22:45 2016-06-05 23:30 New York Unité Spécial Saison 17 Episode 13 RTS Un (Suisse)
```

Desired Output :

```
<div class="alert alert-warning">
 <strong>Diffusions du jour :</strong>
   <hr>
     <ul class="list-inline">
     <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Netflix (France)"><span class="badge progress-bar-danger">09:00</span> <span class="badge alert-success">Outlander</span> <span class="badge progress-bar-warning">Saison 2</span> <span class="badge alert-danger">Episode 9</span></li>
     <br>
     <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="RTS Un (Suisse)"><span class="badge progress-bar-danger">17:55</span> <span class="badge alert-success">Hawaii 5-0 (2010)</span> <span class="badge progress-bar-warning">Saison 6</span> <span class="badge alert-danger">Episode 22</span></li>
     <br>
     <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Téva (France)"><span class="badge progress-bar-danger">20:40</span> <span class="badge alert-success">Madam Secretary</span> <span class="badge progress-bar-warning">Saison 2</span> <span class="badge alert-danger">Episode 13 &amp; 14</span></li>
     <br>
     <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="OCS Choc (France)"><span class="badge progress-bar-danger">20:40</span> <span class="badge alert-success">The Walking Dead</span> <span class="badge progress-bar-warning">Saison 6</span> <span class="badge alert-danger">Episode 7 &amp; 8</span></li>
     <br>
     <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="RTS Un (Suisse)"><span class="badge progress-bar-danger">21:15</span> <span class="badge alert-success">Major Crimes</span> <span class="badge progress-bar-warning">Saison 4</span> <span class="badge alert-danger">Episode 3 &amp; 4</span></li>
     <br>
     <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="OCS Choc (France)"><span class="badge progress-bar-danger">22:10</span> <span class="badge alert-success">Ash vs Evil Dead</span> <span class="badge progress-bar-warning">Saison 1</span> <span class="badge alert-danger">Episode 7 &amp; 8</span></li>
     <br>
     <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="RTS Un (Suisse)"><span class="badge progress-bar-danger">22:45</span> <span class="badge alert-success">New York Unité Spécial</span> <span class="badge progress-bar-warning">Saison 17</span> <span class="badge alert-danger">Episode 13</span></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I change the sample text (remove the \t with while read line).

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
echo "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\">"
echo "<strong>Diffusions du jour :</strong>"
echo "            <hr>"
echo "            <ul class=\"list-inline\">"

while read -r line; do
# Parsing line and stok some infos
# sample line : 2016-06-05 20:40 2016-06-05 22:20 Madam Secretary Saison 2 Episode 13 & 14 Téva (France)
heureDebut=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
NomSerie=$(echo $line | awk -F'[[:space:]]' '{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13}' | sed 's/.Saison.*//')
simpleName=$(echo "${line:34}")
LocationOne=$(echo $simpleName | sed -n -e 's/^.*Episode //p'| sed 's/[0-9]*//g' | cut -c 2-)
LocationTwo=$(echo $simpleName | sed -n -e 's/^.*Episode //p'| sed 's/[0-9]*//g' | cut -c 5-)
Saison=$(echo $simpleName | sed -n -e 's/^.*Saison //p' | awk -F'[^0-9]*' '$0=$1')
TwoEpisode=$(echo $simpleName | sed -n -e 's/^.*Saison //p' | awk -F'[^0-9]*' '$0=$3')
Episode=$(echo $simpleName | sed -n -e 's/^.*Saison //p' | awk -F'[^0-9]*' '$0=$2')
if [ -z "$TwoEpisode" ]
    then
echo "<li data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"right\" title=\""$LocationOne"\"><span class=\"badge progress-bar-danger\">$heureDebut</span> <span class=\"badge alert-success\">"$NomSerie"</span> <span class=\"badge progress-bar-warning\">""Saison"" "$Saison"</span> <span class=\"badge alert-danger\">""Episode"" "$Episode"</span></li>"
echo "<br>"
else
echo "<li data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"right\" title=\""$LocationTwo"\"><span class=\"badge progress-bar-danger\">$heureDebut</span> <span class=\"badge alert-success\">"$NomSerie"</span> <span class=\"badge progress-bar-warning\">""Saison"" "$Saison"</span> <span class=\"badge alert-danger\">""Episode"" "$Episode" ""&"" ""$TwoEpisode""</span></li>"
echo "<br>"
fi
done < $filename
echo "                    </ul>"
echo "                 </div>"
```

The Script works only for the sample text not for other events :'(

Comment: Contrary to what you seem to believe, StackOverflow isn't a free coding service (or exam answering service). You're expected to show your code, along with relevant sample inputs, expected outputs, actual error msgs as well as your comments about where you are stuck. Please show your best effort to solve this problem (and format correctly by using the {} tool at the top left of the edit box), and people may be able to help you.As a hint, read about `printf` as either part of `bash` or `awk`. Good luck.

Comment: Well done!  Upvoting your Q as you have obviously tried to solve your problem. It seems like you're almost there. Can you edit  your Q to mention (at the top of the Q) "I need to know how to do ...." ? Also, we don't need to see 10 lines of data that is "wider" than the display page when all will be processed the same, why not make it 1-2 lines of data of "narrow" data? Good luck!

Comment: I search how to separate the $5 variable ( Outlander Saison 2 Episode 9 ) and show only the name of show but i cant find how to use pattern at the times

Comment: hmm... you're complicating your Q then. You seem to understand how the `printf` works and that your problem is parsing your input. Can you reduce your Q to 1 line of data that works without a problem and 1 (2-3) lines of data that you still need help with? we don't need to worry about the `<li...>` part of this, right? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter 
I drop , I find anything, I do not happen to do anything with a single line, I really have to be zero with awk

Comment: your sample txt is not tab delimited. Is it a correct input ?

Comment: ping me tomorrow if you don't get any help. (but in the mean time read about `substr($0,pos,offset)`, `sub(/old/,"new",$0)` and `match($0,regex/)` "near" http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-43 ). Good luck.

Comment: @chef : I've never seen an actual tab char in a S.O. posting. I think, given the formatting, that `tab` is implied. ... yes? Definitely going to bed now! ;-) Good luck to all!